# Whats the equivalent of glColor4f in OpenGLESv2?

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

I currently need to port an application from GL to GLESv2 and I am wondering what the corresponding call for `glColor4f` in OpenGL ES 2.0 is.

I have read about `glVertexAttrib4f` but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

glColor4f is part of the old fixed function pipeline, and that is now deprecated. There were usually two use cases for glColor4f....

1. To set a colour prior to rendering a model, so that the whole model had the same colour.
2. To set a different colour for each vertex.

In GLSL based OpenGL, you now have to do those with:

1. Create a uniform vec4 in your shader, use glGetUniformLocation to get the location of your "colour" attribute, then use glUniform4f to set the value.
2. Create an in varying vec4 in your shader, use glGetAttribLocation to query the location for your "vert_colour" attribute, and then to specify the colour data, use glVertexAttribXX if you *really* want to mimic the old glBegin/glEnd approach, or preferably use glVertexAttribPointer to tell the shader to read the data from a VBO.